# I get this error mail every time I login to my web server, what does it mean?

Tags: mail

```
Message 1:
From root@server.myserver.net  Wed May  2 03:01:02 2012
Date: Wed, 2 May 2012 03:01:02 +0400
From: root@server.myserver.net (Cron Daemon)
To: root@server.myserver.net
Subject: Cron <root@server> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
head: cannot open `status' for reading: No such file or directory
sed: can't read status: No such file or directory
```

and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the following blog link for a detailed discussion: http://teklimbu.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/managing-your-linuxunix-log-files-using-logrotate/

A quick and dirty trick would be to `touch` or create an empty file `/var/lib/logrotate/status` on your server.

Just a brief background:

`logrotate` is a utility which can *rotate* log files and archive them in a specified location.

`cron` is a service which can be used to schedule to run/automate specific tasks.

Now, apparently, since *cron* on the server is scheduled to run the *logrotate* script daily, which in turn expects the *status* file to be present (which doesn't exist), your server is throwing these error messages.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was similar to the other one but clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have a look at /etc/cron.daily/logrotate - you will find that the script is checking for the existence of (and capability to write to): /var/lib/logrotate/status

In my /etc/cron.daily/logrotate script, there is a line that precedes the head command that will first test for the existence of, OR create (with touch) the "status" file:
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean

Probably yours is not able to write the "status" file to "/var/lib/logrotate/" with the touch command? I would cd into /var/lib/logrotate//logrotate and see if I could manually create the "status" file(assuming it doesn't exist there already) with the command: touch status . Maybe there's no disk space left for that directory? Check with df -h /var/lib/logrotate/ , or maybe it's set to be immutable (dunno why this would be).